# Line Breaks in Go - Understanding this example from Go Tour

Tags: go

I am trying to understand this example from the Go Tour.
What is the significance of this last comma on line 3

```
fmt.Println(
    pow(3, 2, 10),
    pow(3, 3, 20),
)
```

How do line breaks generally modify the code in go.
I know, that without the line breaks, I can write this statement as

```
fmt.Println( pow(3, 2, 10), pow(3, 3, 20) )
```

and it would compile.
So, why is the extra comma needed with line breaks

Answer (score 2):

Go "automatically" adds `;` as the end of a statement.

So

```
fmt.Println(
    pow(3, 2, 10),
    pow(3, 3, 20),
)
```

as the same as

```
fmt.Println(
    pow(3, 2, 10),
    pow(3, 3, 20),
);
```

But

```
fmt.Println(
    pow(3, 2, 10),
    pow(3, 3, 20)
)
```

is the same as

```
fmt.Println(
    pow(3, 2, 10),
    pow(3, 3, 20);
);
```

which is obvioulsy a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

There's no significance. Trailing commas are allowed in function calls, although `go fmt` will remove them.